# 'module' object has no attribute 'svc'

Tags: python, python-2.7, svm

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm

### Read the CSV ###
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/anagha/Documents/Python Scripts/sampleData.csv')
df

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(df, train_size = 0.8)
train
test

x_column=['Userid','day_of_week','hour_of_day','minute_of_hour']
y_column = ['thermostat']

svc = svm.SVC()
model = svm.svc(kernel='linear', c=1, gamma=1)
```

I'm getting an error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'svc'. Tried many techniques, but none of them are working. I'm new to python, and would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 9):

```
svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, gamma=1)
```

Note that capital `C`.

See the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC).

Comment: This still does not work for me. So strange. Tried every solution here.

Comment: What exactly is your code and what error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
```

then

```
model = SVC(kernel='linear', c=1, gamma=1)
```

worked fine for me

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1,gamma=1)
```

'C' must be in capital

Answer (score 2):

Im using sklearn version 0.18

my problem was solved

```
from sklearn import svm
```

change for

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
```

Comment: Please be reminded that for a single-state answer, you can also use the comment section of the answer.  For instance, in the comment section "You can convert `svm` to `SVC`"

Answer (score 1):

The error come from you code below:

```
model = svm.svc(kernel='linear', c=1, gamma=1)
```

After you use :

```
svc = svm.SVC()
```

svc is an object produced by svm.SVC(). So I guess what you want is :

```
model = svc(kernel='linear', c=1, gamma=1)
```

or

```
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', c=1, gamma=1)
```

Wish this could help~

Answer (score 1):

Your problem originate from the fact that you call:

```
model = svm.svc(kernel='linear', c=1, gamma=1)
```

with lowercase svc in svm.svc, which should be **svm.SVC**. Additionally, as Alex Hall noted, you call c=1 with in lower case which should be C=1. Giving:

```
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, gamma=1)
```